# Почему не устанавливается Gulp?

Tags: gulp, npm

Всем добрый день! Не устанавливается Gulp

Перелопатил тут вопросы по проблемам с установкой Gulp, но ответа на мою проблему не нашел(

Версия node - 19.3.0, npm, npx - 9.2.0

Мои действия: `npm init` (заполнил package.json все по дефолту), `npm install --save-dev gulp`.
После этого в консоли выдает следующее:

```
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies

npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

added 350 packages, and audited 351 packages in 14s

12 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

и в итоге Gulp не установлен.

Пробовал и `npm audit fix`, и `npm audit fix --force`. Ничего не помогает.

Возможно, кто-то может подсказать как решить проблему?

P.S. удалял Gulp и глобально и локально, не помогает.

Comment: В приведенном листинге нет ошибки. Только варнинги. Как вы определили, что gulp не установлен?

Comment: Ну, во-первых, в конце команды нет оповещения об успешной установке модуля, как это обычно бывает при успешной установке модуля. А во-вторых написал gulp --version, а в ответ получил: ""gulp" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом." Хотя в файлах package.json и в package-lock.json появились зависимости и подзависимости gulp соответственно. Но в любом ide и консоли версию галпа не показывает(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В приведенном листинге нет ошибок, только предупреждения. Вы пишите в комментариях, что "нет оповещения об успешной установке модуля, как это обычно бывает при успешной установке модуля", но строка

```
packages, and audited 351 packages in 14s
```

как раз говорит об успешной установке пакетов. Убедиться, что `gulp` установлен, вы можете, исходя из содержимого поля `devDependencies` вашего `package.json` либо запустив из директории проекта команду

```
npm list --depth 0
```

При этом команда `gulp` в системном терминале и не должна заработать, т.к вы устанавливаете его не глобально. Если вы хотите использовать его глобально, необходимо использовать ключ `-g`:

```bash
npm i gulp -g
```

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек!) Благодаря вашему ответу я разобрался и все получилось. Вопрос закрыт

Comment: Хорошо, я рад. В таком случае можете зачесть ответ.